# Why is Facebook sharing erratic on a Wordpress site?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, wordpress-theming, facebook-social-plugins

I have a strange issue here.

A Wordpress site developed by us for a client, www.oasisplace.com.my has issues sharing blog posts.

In each blog post's bottom there is a Facebook sharing icon.

If clicked on the Facebook sharing dialog appears.

For some users, the featured image is replaced with the Facebook icon itself. For some others it is simply a blank image.
However for me and a few of the development team, the post gets shared normally with visible featured image.

Is there anything that can be done to resolve this?

My assumption is something screwed up during the migration from a staging server (with different site URL) to the production server for official deployment.

Thanks.

Comment: Are `og:` tags being created?

Comment: @TecBrat Yes they are. I have got pointers to try the og:property instead?

Comment: Yeah, the answer by "Will" will probably end up being correct

Answer (score 2):

If you include

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.oasisplace.com.my/path/to/image.jpg"/>
```

or

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[image url]"/>
```

Facebook should pick it up consistently.

Getting those things into the header on a WordPress site can be a pita.

http://werewp.com/wordpress/how-to-integrate-facebook-open-graph-protocol-into-your-wordpress-theme/ uses a secondary loop inside of header.php (or wherever your <head> section is located). Seems inefficient but probably works.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<?php if (have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();endwhile;endif;?>
>
<?php if (is_single()) { ?>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/path/to-your/logo.jpg" />
<?php } ?>
```

I've taken to including the Yoast SEO plugin on all sites I build these days. One of the reasons is that it handles the Facebook header stuff for us. It uses sensible defaults and allows you to overwrite those defaults on any given post.

Comment: Hi @Will I have tried installing the Yoast SEO plugin and enabled the relevant areas but the second post still seems to share just the icon.
Placing the URL / permalink into the Facebook Developer debug, the Facebook servers seem to pull three images into the og:image, including the Facebook share icon. However the previous works properly with the proper featured image. Is there anything else that needs to be done?